# Add class based on window size jQuery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, responsive

I want my page to add a grid system when the window width is > 1000px. I hoped adding this script to the HTML would work, but when using the inspector, I do not see any new classes on the targeted elements. Any suggestions?

```
if ($(window).width() >= 1000) {
    var dA = document.getElementById('divA');
    var dB = document.getElementById('divB');
    var n1 = document.getElementById("num1");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("num2");
    var n3 = document.getElementById("num3");
    var n4 = document.getElementById("num4");
    var n5 = document.getElementById("num5");
    var n6 = document.getElementById("num6");

    dA.className += " row ";
    dB.className += " row ";
    n1.className += " col-md-3 ";
    n2.className += " col-md-3 ";
    n3.className += " col-md-3 ";
    n4.className += " col-md-3 ";
    n5.className += " col-md-3 ";
    n6.className += " col-md-3 ";
}
```

Comment: what is `$(window).width` returning that you expect it to work?

Comment: It returns the width of the viewport as an integer.

Comment: Why JS? Those elements should have the classes set right away in the HTML source code, and then you use media queries to only apply formatting on those classes from a certain breakpoint.

Comment: why aren't you using jquery to add class names like: `$('#divA').addClass('row')`

Comment: Your class names reminds me of Bootstrap. If you in fact are using Bootstrap you could customize it here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
Don't for get that elements can have various classes as well.

Comment: @CBroe, you are correct. This is a better solution. I am using Bootstrap as entiendoNull noticed, and was afraid the columns would be too wide on smaller screens. Foolish of me to forget that it is designed to collapse into vertical stacks!!

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery ,

Use like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($(window).width() >= 1000) {

        $("#divA").addClass("row");

        //And other codes
    }

})
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine. I can almost guarantee you that you're calling it too soon. Since you're using jquery, put your code inside of this:

```
 $(function(){
    // your code goes here
 });
```

This function gets called when the dom is ready, so your elements are now ready to be modified anyway you want.